# NSOutlineView and selection index paths

Tags: cocoa, selection, nsoutlineview

I want to get/set the selection index paths of an `NSOutlineView`. How do I do this?

There is no obvious method that gets/sets the selection index paths.

If you try to bind the selection index paths, and you don't bind them to a tree controller, it doesn't work at all.

The outline view doesn't really seem to understand the concept of selection index paths. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Save the selection state without bindings using code such as:

```
NSIndexSet* theSelectedRows = [self.tableView selectedRowIndexes];
NSMutableArray* selectedItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[theSelectedRows enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger i, BOOL *stop) {
    [selectedItems addObject:[self.tableView itemAtRow:i]];
    // or add some other identifier specific to your data model
}];
```

To be notified when the view's selection changes, set a delegate for your NSOutlineView and in that delegate implement:

```
- (void)outlineViewSelectionDidChange: (NSNotification *)notification
```

Comment: No. I want the selection index paths, not the selected row indexes.

Comment: Well you're not using an NSTreeController, so the 'selection index path' is going to need to be a custom solution based on your custom data model.  Your model must include references to parent node, yes?  You can use the answer above (it is not storing row indexes btw) to instead store an NSArray of objects that lead to your root.